Why is PDC radiation someties emitted as a hollow cone and sometimes appears as a 2D gaussian?
Common depictions of PDC radiation depict it as a hollow cone being emitted. In the imaging plane, this then appears as a circle. See for example the following picture from this arXiv upload:

On the other hand, sometimes the measured spectrum looks like a 2D gaussian (with additional oscillations):

The image was found here.
What is the difference between those two situations (apart from the differente of type-I and type-II phase matching)? Why is one spectrum "hollow" and the other not?

One (the first) is in real space; the second pair are in frequency space? As you have not included the captions or labelled   the axes in the second pair, it is impossible to say...

@mikestone I added the source for the second image, which includes the caption. Both images are in the spatial domain.

My understanding of the phrase "spatial spectrum" is that it is the Fourier transform of the spatial intensity. If so it is not a real-space image. I may be completely wrong, and I have not found the whole review article.

Consider to spell out acronyms.

The are different phase-matching conditions that can be used in parametric down-conversion. In the top image, the type II phase matching condition is used, where the two down-converted photon, each associated with one of the two circles in the images, have opposite polarizations.
Another one is type I phase matching, where the two down-converted photons have the same polarization. In that case (assuming they have the same wavelength) both photons are produced on opposite point of the same circle. However, the cone angle (down-conversion angle) can be reduced to zero for collinear phase matching in which case the photons would be propagating in a single beam. In that case the images (in the far field) would not shown a hollow beam. The bottom images may be representing such a case.
